# Changing Android's WebView display from Desktop Mode back to Mobile Mode

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm developing a browser which is supposed to allow toggling between mobile and desktop modes. 
When changing to desktop mode via the following code:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.reload();
```

It's all good. However, when trying to change back to mobile mode via the following code:

```
  mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; HTC One X Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.58 Mobile Safari/537.31");
  mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
  mWebView.reload();
```

The page is reloaded, but it's still displayed in desktop mode. 
It's worth noting that when testing this on YouTube, after triggering the 2nd code segment I AM able to return to mobile mode if I manually insert "https://m.youtube.com" into the address bar (something which is not possible when in desktop mode and before triggering the 2nd code segment). So it seems that resetting the UserAgent, while not providing the desired result, is not worthless after all.

So, assuming that changing the domain prefix from "www" to "m" programmatically is a somewhat hacky solution, how can mobile mode be automatically restored?

**Edit:**

As for clearing WebView's cookies - it solves the problem, but it seems that while it is trivial to clear ALL cookies, that is not the case when trying to clear only those cookies which belong to a specific domain. Clearing everything is not an option in my case.

Comment: Does this happen only on a specific website or on all websites ? Could you clear cookies in the WebView ?

Comment: @JonasCz - Thank you, I've edited the question (I've already tried that, but it creates another problem).

Comment: In that case, I don't know what could be done, but I guess that it's due to this specific website "caching" the value of the useragent and thus weather to serve the desktop or mobile page. Perhaps you could try to find some way to clear individual cookies (I'm sure this is possible somehow), or see how other, open source browser apps do it, eg. Lightning (on GitHub). I'll investigate and see if I can come up with something.